# One mystery string in Java

Tags: java

Say I have jar file `jarA` and `jarB`.

`class A` is in `jarA`:

```
class A {
  public static final String SQL = "select `col1`, `col2`, ... `col50` from `table`";
}
```

`class B` is in `jarB`:

```
class B {
    public void loadData() {
        String sql = "some other sql";
        ...
        A a = null;
        sql = a.SQL + " where something = something"; //This actually works, I never thought about it before I saw this code. 
        executeSQL(sql); //jdbc stuff
    }
}
```

When I run (and later debug) `jarB` with `jarA` in the class path, weird thing happened:

1. the sql executed was missing `col25`, it was like `select col1, col2, ..., col24, col26, ..., col50 from ...`
2. when I debug it, paused somewhere before the `executeSQL(sql)` thing, I ran some expressions below:

   `A.SQL` returns the correct string(with `col25`)

   `a.SQL` also returns correctly

   `sql` is almost correct except that `col25` is not there

I added `-verbose:class` at startup, I can see that `class A` was indeed loaded from `jarA`. Then I unzipped `jarA`, found `A.class`, reverse engineered it, I can see the string `SQL` is correct.

I know there's definitely something wrong. But any suggestions where I should look into, or any wild guesses?

Comment: Could you print the exact value of the "sql" variable ?

Comment: and add the executeSql method

Comment: recompile A then B it should work

Comment: @Berger it's actually a select statement with over 50 columns, I don't see anything special, and it actually happened with another class before.

Comment: Quick sanity check, did you properly clean your project? i.e. clean jarA and jarB such that jarB uses the correct version of jarA which uses the correct version of classA?

It just sounds like classA might be out of date in jarB, or classA exists in jarB as well?

Comment: @Shiraaz.M well I can see `A` was loaded from `jarA` with `-verbose:class`. And I unzipped `jarA`, reverse engineered `A`, the `SQL` was correct. So am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL is a compile-time constant. That means that, when **compiling** the class B, the `A.SQL` string value will be inlined in B's byte-code.

So, my guess is that col25 was missing in A.SQL, B was compiled against this incorrect class, then A.SQL was fixed and recompiled, but B was not recompiled. So its bytecode still contains the incorrect sql string.

Recompile B, or, if SQL is not actually a constant (i.e. a value that will never, ever, ever change), then don't expose it as a public constant. Instead, define a method returning the SQL string, and use that method from the B class.

Comment: Inlining could be an explanation but in my case, `A.jar` was compiled first(there was a maven dependency in B). Anyway I'll check it out when I'm back to work